# In Perl, how can I convert arrays I read from database into a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl

Basically, I'm querying a database and I need to convert the resultant array to a hash.

I query the database as follows

```
my $sth = $dbw->prepare($sql);
while (@rows = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {  
...
...
}
```

Now, I need to create a hash such that rows[0] is the key and rows[1],rows[2],rows[3] are the values. For each record read, a new hash key has to be generated and the corresponding values set

If my tables look like

```
abc 2.3 2.4 2.5
def 3.2 3.3 3.4
ijk 4.5 4.6 4.7
```

First record is read and abc is the key and the numbers are the values...so on

Answer (score 7):

You could also have a look at [selectall_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#selectall_hashref).

```
$hash_ref = $dbh->selectall_hashref($statement, $key_field);
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter you addressed that comment to, but this doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @Kinopiko: for me this gives an hashref containing retrieved rows indexed by a key, that is what the OP wants or i'm missing something.

Comment: I assumed that the poster wanted to have an array containing the values from each row rather than a hash reference.

Answer (score 6):

```
my %hash;

while (my @fields = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {  
    $hash{$fields[0]} = [ @fields[1..$#fields] ];
}
```

Comment: How does the hash look in this case? Is it like `$rows[0] => @var`

Comment: @Aks: hash values are scalars. So it is `$rows[0] => \@var`

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont know what \@ means

Comment: Don't name your variable `@rows`, it only contains one row at a time, so call it `@row`.

Answer (score 4):

```
my %mealsizes;
my $sth = $dbw->prepare($sql);
while (@columns = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {  
  my $dayname = shift @columns;
  $mealsizes{$dayname} = [@columns];
}
```

Here's an illustration of constructing and using an arrayref.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;
while (<DATA>) {
  my @columns = split;
  my $k = shift @columns;
  $h{$k} = [@columns];
}

for my $k (sort keys %h) {
  print "$k => ", join(', ', @{$h{$k}}), "\n";
}

__DATA__
abc 2.3 2.4 2.5
def 3.2 3.3 3.4
ijk 4.5 4.6 4.7
```